# Oxidation states of Cu in YBa2Cu3O6 based on crystal structure

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, solid-state-chemistry

How does on go about this? I understand There is a +5 charge distributed on 3 copper ions. So either we have 2+, 2+ and 1+ or 3+, 1+, and 1+. Judging from the structure there are to unequivalent types of Cu ions. But how does one determine which is which and if the formal charges are +2 and +1 or +3 and +1 respectively

Any help is appreciated
[image]

Comment: You don't, really.  Oxidation state is just a formalism.  The positive charges on copper are likely delocalized.

Comment: You're talking about *oxidation states, not formal charges...